# Reduce padding in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to obtain a graph using ggplot2. The problem is that I am not able to reduce the white-space between the legend border and the text. For example: [image: sample legend],

In this, I want to reduce the white space at the top that I have marked with some curly lines.

I searched a lot, but at most places, the answers suggest to reduce the `key.height` or `key.width`, but that is not what I want; I am pretty happy with those. I just want to get rid of the white space at the top.

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing a reproducible example, but how about `theme(legend.title=element_blank())`.

Comment: That's what I did to remove the legend title. This did remove the legend title, but left the white-space. I want to remove this white-space.

Comment: Then use `legend.margin=margin(c(1,5,5,5))` and play around with the values (they're in the order top, right, bottom, left) until you get something you like.

Answer (score 16):

You can remove the space for the legend title with:

```
theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

If that's not sufficient then do:

```
theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
      legend.margin=margin(c(1,5,5,5)))
```

and play around with the values (they're in the order top, right, bottom, left) until you get something you like.

Comment: I am getting this error: could not find function "margin"

Comment: What version of ggplot2 are you using? I think you might need the latest version (2.2.0) for this solution to work. If you have an earlier version of ggplot, I think the equivalent would be something like `legend.margin=unit(c(1,5,5,5), "pt")` but I'm not positive. That might just change the margin around the legend panel.

Answer (score 5):

The other solutions have not worked in my case as there was still whitespace at the top.

Setting

```
theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
      legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
      legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"),
      legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"))
```

removed **all** the white space.