# ggplot legend without title leaves space for title

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a ggplot that doesn't require a legend because it actually *has a title* and thus doesn't need a legend that would simply repeat the title.
Imagine something like this:

```
ggplot(iris)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+
  theme(legend.box.background=element_rect(fill="white", color="black"))+
  labs(color="")+
  ggtitle("Sepals ~ Species")+
  xlab("Length")+
  ylab("Width")
```

(*ignore* the fact that the legend in my reprex only has two lines drawn for the box)

Do you notice the graphical problem? Apparently ggplot "thinks" there is a legend title and leaves some space, so I though using element_blank for the legend title might work.

```
ggplot(iris)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+
  labs(color=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.box.background=element_rect(fill=NA, color="black"),
        legend.margin=margin(t=0,r=0,b=0,l=0))+
  ggtitle("Sepals ~ Species")+
  xlab("Length")+
  ylab("Width")
```

While this improves the situation by making the box smaller at the top, it does *not* fix the problem because the top space is still smaller. As I have manually set the legend margins to 0 this can't be the issue.

**any ideas?**

Answer (score 2):

You can set `theme(legend.title = element_blank())` . This also means you don't need to set an empty string for the label.

To show this, let's make that box outline a little thicker, and use the "empty string" method:

```r
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  ggtitle("Sepals ~ Species") +
  labs(x = "Length", y = "Width", color = "") +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color ="black", size = 2))
```

[image]

We can see that there is an obvious space where the title should be.

But now let's try it with the `element_blank()` method:

```r
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  ggtitle("Sepals ~ Species") +
  labs(x = "Length", y = "Width") +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color ="black", size = 2),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

As Tjebo points out, the other option is to use `NULL` instead of an empty string, which does the same thing as `theme(legend.title = element_blank())`

```r
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  ggtitle("Sepals ~ Species") +
  labs(x = "Length", y = "Width", color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color ="black", size = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: that's why I try to convince people to use NULL instead of an empty character

Comment: That's a good point @tjebo - I'll add that in.

Comment: however, this is the same as my element_blank()-solution. The top margin is still *way* larger than the bottom one. Trust me, I measured it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You additionally need to change `legend.spacing`. Very related: [Reduce padding in ggplot2 legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389351/reduce-padding-in-ggplot2-legend)

By the way, `margin()` has as defaults all = 0, so you don't need to type them out... ;)

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+
  labs(color=NULL) +
  theme(legend.box.background=element_rect(fill="white", color="black"), 
        legend.margin=margin(), 
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>